# Django / Django rest framework view uncaught exception

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When I have DEBUG=True in my settings I can see the following error

```
Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in view
116.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
495.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
455.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
492.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in create
21.         self.perform_create(serializer)

File "/device_mgmt/selection/views.py" in perform_create
84.             serializer.save(realm=utils.get_realm_from_request(self.request))

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in save
214.             self.instance = self.create(validated_data)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in create
943.             instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in create
422.         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)

File "/device_mgmt/selection/models.py" in save
123.         self.full_clean()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in full_clean
1203.             raise ValidationError(errors)

Exception Type: ValidationError at /company/api/company/
Exception Value: {'id': ['Company with this Id already exists.']}
```

The model is throwing an error but the rest framework view is calling
`455.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)`

How can I make it so that rest framework uses the exception from the django model?  I thought this would get handled automatically as the exception has the info about what went wrong.

When it gets returned, all I have is a 500 with `<h1>Server error<h1>`.

I would not assume that I have to catch the exception and do some special handling on it since it is a basic django ValidationError.

Is the issue caused because rest framework also has a ValidationError type?

Answer (score 0):

From drf docs:

> The handled exceptions are:
>
> Subclasses of APIException raised inside REST framework.
>
> Django's Http404 exception.
>
> Django's PermissionDenied exception.

So no. drf wont handle the exception you are referring to.

Here it says that you can implement your own exception handling:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling

Comment: ok thanks. Weird it doesn't handle those other django exceptions. They seem very common.  And it is not "My exception" it is a django exception on the model. I did not create it.